# Android Location Background service with handler time delay

Tags: java, android, location

Can I use handler in location service for better battery efficiency?
My app have a service which works in background, and various settings time for delay within update location (GET_LOCATION_TIME).
I use loop handler to start and stop FusedLocationApi, when I retrieved location - send it to Firebase.

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    handler.postDelayed(this, updateTime);
    startLocationUpdates();
    if (myLocation != null) {
        mFirebaseDatabaseHelper.updateUserLocation(myLocation);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopLocationUpdates();

        }
    }, GET_LOCATION_TIME);
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    //handle unexpected permission absence
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, createLocationRequest(), this);
        }
    } else {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); //1 secs
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100); //1 secs
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1f); //1 m

    return mLocationRequest;

}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```